# Integral of holomorphic function as sum

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I have a function $f(z)$ which can be represented as a power series for any $z$ inside a disc of radius R $\left(\text{i.e, for any } z\in D(a,R)\right)$. I have to show that for $0\leq r<R$ it's true that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(a+re^{it})\lvert^2dt=2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert a_n \lvert^2r^{2n}$$

$\textbf{My guess:}$

As $f$ is representable as power series, I have tried:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(a+re^{it}) \lvert^2 \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^ne^{itn} \right\lvert^2 \, dt =\cdots(\text{manipulating})\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\lvert^2 r^{2n} \int_0^{2\pi}e^{2int} \, dt$$

But from that point on, whatever I try I do not manage to get the $2\pi$ to get it out of the sum. Maybe I am going in the right direction and I making mistakes, I do not know. I have tried to get $e^{2int}$ in the form of $sin$ and $cos$, but I still do not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. $f(re^{i\theta}) \bar{f(re^{i\theta}})=|f(re^{i\theta})|^2$ . Τhen you use the power series of f inside the integral $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n r^ne^{in\theta}\right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bar{a_n} r^ne^{-in\theta}\right)d\theta$$  You multiply the normal series and its conjugate. That is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (a_0+a_1re^{i\theta}+a_2r^2e^{2i\theta}+...)(\bar{a_0}+\bar{a_1}re^{-i\theta}+\bar{a_2}r^2e^{-2i\theta}+...)d\theta $$ (Do the multiplication for the first 3 terms ) What you get is this: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \bar{a_n} r^n r^n e^{in\theta} e^{-in\theta} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n r^ne^{i n\theta} d\theta$$ Now because the series converges uniformly in your disc you can change the order of summation and integration in the 1st integral which is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2r^{2n}  d\theta$$  or $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2r^{2n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}1 d\theta$$ which gives us $2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2r^{2n} $. Now about the second integral ,which is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nr^ne^{in\theta}$$ you just need to see that you integrate a $2\pi$ -periodic function over $[0,2\pi]$ so every integral is zero because of periodicity. These $b_n$ terms are nothing but combinations of $a_n$ terms multiplicated with $\bar{a_m}$ for $m\ne n$ . If you do the calculations for the 1st three terms you will see what happens and what remains is zero because of periodicity so you have the result.

Comment: Can I put the integral inside both sums? I mean $\sum\int a\ldots d\theta\sum\int\overline{a}\ldots d\theta$

Comment: No just multiply the series. You will get $\sum^{n=0}_{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}+\int_{0}^{2\pi} ...$ where the dots represent a function of $e^{i\theta} $. The remaining integrals are all zero because you integrate a periodic function of period $2\pi$ in $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: And, what about the $2\pi$ in front of the $\sum$ in the question?

Comment: The sum comes out of the integral and what remains is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}\int _{0}^{2\pi}1 d\theta$ so this is why you have $2\pi$ is here

Comment: You can change the order of summation integration order because power series converges uniformly inside the disc

Comment: If you write the solution, I'll mark it as correct and upvote it! Thanks!

Comment: I will edit my answer now ok?

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot

Comment: I have a question (which maybe is simple), but, in the first integral ($\int\sum\sum d\theta$) the limits are $-\pi,\pi$? Or $0,2\pi$?

Comment: It is the same . Either $[0,2\pi],[-\pi,\pi]$ is the same. I just wrote the solution i had done when this excercise was given to me. But dont worry it us the exact same thing!